# Add Login to GhostDoc generated help website

Tags: c#, vb.net, iis, documentation, ghostdoc

I have a project with XML comments all set up and the documentation is being generated as expected but my boss would like to put the documentation itself behind a log in so its not freely accessible.

Is this something I could do by adding a landing page and setting something up in IIS? Or, would I have to add something to each individual page to force it to ensure someone had logged in who had permission to see the doc? Or, other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple ways.

You could setup some security in IIS on a virtual directory so users are required to authenticate in a number of ways. This option does not require you to be a programmer but does take more work to setup and administer.

The other option is to put a web.config in the same folder as your document that has standard login/redirect directives. Then you could have it redirect the user to a login page, which you create in ASP, and then send them back.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, they both sound fairly viable so do you know of any tutorials for either option? Or what a good search term would be to find them on my own?

Comment: "configure iis security by virtual directory" or "securing a folder with web.config"